# Prove that ${\sqrt {n} }^{\sqrt {n+1}} > {\sqrt {n+1}}^{\sqrt {n}}$.

Tags: calculus, induction, exponentiation

Which is greater? $\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n+1}}$ or $\sqrt{n+1}^\sqrt{n}$

I know that $\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n+1}}$ is greater but I tried using induction and I couldn't figure it out. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It starts at $n=7$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac1x\log(x)=\frac1{x^2}(1-\log(x))<0$ for $x\gt e$. Therefore, $x^{1/x}$ is a decreasing function for $x\gt e$. Thus, for $\sqrt{n}\ge e$, i.e. $n\gt e^2$,
$$
\sqrt{n+1}^{1/\sqrt{n+1}}\lt\sqrt{n}^{1/\sqrt{n}}\\
\Updownarrow\\
\sqrt{n+1}^{\sqrt{n}}\lt\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n+1}}
$$

Comment: $4>e$, and yet $\sqrt{4+1}^{\sqrt{4}}>\sqrt{4}^{\sqrt{4+1}}$. The same is true for $n\leq6$.

Comment: Ah, I think then you want to have "for $\sqrt{n}\geq e$"

Comment: The inequality is valid for $n\geq 7$. Not valid for $n\leq 6$. I like your proof the best, +1.

Comment: @alex.jordan: oops... I forgot that the argument of $x^{1/x}$ is $\sqrt{n}$, not $n$. Corrected :-)

Comment: @robjohn How will we show that this inequality is also true for $n = 7 < e^2 $ ?

Comment: This method works well for $n\ne7$. However, since $x^{1/x}$ reaches a maximum at $e$ which is between $\sqrt7$ and $\sqrt8$, we simply have to compute $\sqrt7^{\sqrt8}=15.6729$ and $\sqrt8^{\sqrt7}=15.6558$.

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on what $n$ is.

Consider a fixed $a$, and let $f(x)=x^a$ and $g(x)=a^x$. At $x=a$, both functions have equal output. Let's examine their derivatives at $x=a$:
$$f'(a) = a^a$$
$$g'(a) = a^a\ln(a)$$
Generally $g$ has the larger derivative at $x=a$, as long as $a>e$. Again as long as $a>e$, after the point at which $f$ and $g$ are equal, $g$ has higher output values.

So let's take $a=\sqrt{n}$ and assume for a bit that $\sqrt{n}>e$. Since $\sqrt{n+1}$ is greater than $a$, we will have that $g(\sqrt{n+1})>f(\sqrt{n+1})$, or rather:
$$\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sqrt{n+1}^{\sqrt{n}}$$

For values of $n$ smaller than $e^2$, you could just examine those $n$ values individually. For $n=7$, this direction is still true, but the inequality reverses for $n=0\ldots6$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just another version of
"$n^{1/n}$ is decreasing for $n > e$"
that pops up here every so often.
I and others have provided a number of proofs of this.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: take logarithms of both sides and approximate for sufficiently large $n$.

$$\log{\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n+1}}} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n+1} \log{n}$$

For sufficiently large $n$, this is approximately

$$-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n} \log \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \log
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{16} \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2} \log
   \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{5/2}\right)$$

$$\log{\sqrt{n+1}^{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{n} \log{(n+1)}$$

For sufficiently large $n$, this is approximately

$$-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{n} \log \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}-\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{3/2}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^{5/2}\right)$$

The latter expression is greater than the former when $n > e^2$.  Because the log is monotonic, then

$$\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n+1}} > \sqrt{n+1}^{\sqrt{n}}$$

when $n > e^2$.

Comment: I tried that but it wasn't clear that one is greater than the other.

Comment: Something is not quite right since the inequality is in the other direction for $n=0\ldots6$.

Comment: No, that's OK.  I expanded for "sufficiently large $n$," which turns out to be $n > e^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general result that might be of some use. If we have two functions, $s(n)\mathrm{\ and\ } b(n)$ ("small" and "big") where $c < s(n) < b(n)$ for some constant $c\ge e$, (as usual, $e$ is the base for the natural log) then
$$
b(n)^{s(n)} < s(n)^{b(n)}
$$
In other words, roughly speaking, "small-to-the-big beats big-to-the small." In what follows, you might find it helpful to know that $f(n) = n / \log n$ is a strictly increasing function for $n \ge e$.

If $f$ is strictly increasing, we have that if $A < B$ then $f(A) < f(B)$, so since $s(n) < b(n)$ we'll have
$$
\frac{s(n)}{\log s(n)} < \frac{b(n)}{\log b(n)}
$$
Multiplying both sides of the inequality by the denominators yields
$$
s(n)\log b(n) < b(n) \log s(n)
$$
and using the power property of logs gives 
$$
\log(b(n)^{s(n)}) < \log(s(n)^{b(n)})
$$
Since the log function is also strictly increasing we may conclude
$$
b(n)^{s(n)} < s(n)^{b(n)}
$$
as required. As an example, we can conclude that $n^{\log n} < (\log n)^n$ and, for your question, $\sqrt{n+1}^{\sqrt n} < {\sqrt n}^{\sqrt{n+1}}$ (for all $n$ sufficiently large).