# How can I analyze the asymptotic order of $n^{\ln n}$ and $(\ln n)^n$

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to analyze the asymptotic order of $n^{\ln n}$ and $(\ln n)^n$ At first, I take $\ln$ to both-hand-sides. So I got $(\ln n)^2$ and $n\ln(\ln n))$. However, I don't know what I should do next.

Actually, my friends said, substitute $n = e^k$, but I'm not sure about this approach. How can I analyze these two expressions?

Comment: What do you mean by "analyze" exactly? Also, order-theory is not the right tag, and I have removed it.

Comment: Your somewhat odd TeX code makes me wonder if you meant $(\ln n)^n$ instead of $\ln n^n$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Based on the result of taking $\ln$, I believe you are right.

Comment: @MichaelHardy My purpose was $(\ln n)^n$. Sorry for that.

Comment: I suppose you're asking for which one to be the 'biggest':
Let $n=e^k$ as your friend suggests.
Then you're having $n^{\ln n}=e^{k^2}$ and $(\ln n)^n=k^{e^k}$. Now, for $k$ great enough you have that $k>e$ and $e^k>k^2$, so $k^{e^k}>e^{k^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Considering $n=\mathrm e^k$ is not necessary.

By the step you explain, one wants to compare $\exp((\ln n)^2)$ and $\exp(n\ln\ln n)$. Every power of $\ln n$ is negligible when compared to every (positive) power of $n$,hence  $(\ln n)^2\ll n\ll n\ln\ln n$. This is more than enough to conclude that $\exp((\ln n)^2)\ll\exp(n)\ll\exp(n\ln\ln n)$ since these last comparisons are in fact equivalent to $n-(\ln n)^2\to+\infty$ and $n\ln\ln n-n\to+\infty$.

To sum up, $n\ln\ln n-(\ln n)^2\to+\infty$ hence $n^{\ln n}=\exp((\ln n)^2)\ll\exp(n\ln\ln n)=(\ln n)^n$, in the sense that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\ln n}}{(\ln n)^n}=0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

A more general technique applies here. If you have two functions $s(n) < b(n)$ then under some minor additional conditions you'll have
$$
s(n)^{b(n)} > b(n)^{s(n)}
$$
In loose terms, "small-to-the-big beats big-to-the-small." For a proof of this, refer to
[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317383/proof-for-power-functions/317468#317468).